# PowerShell script to cut paste the folder content in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: powershell-2.0

How can I delete all the contents of one folder (present in C drive) and copy it in another new folder present in different drive (say F).

Example:

C drive→window→ users →temp (make it empty).
move all the content in
F drive→ Temp_backup

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

Move-Item -Path "from" -Destination "to"

like described here:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/848b28c2-1ec2-405a-aebd-48bf79a9594f/how-to-move-files-from-one-location-to-another-location-using-powershell?forum=winserverpowershell

Comment: i tried the same but getting error that u dont have access even if i am using powershell as admin